# class file design of oophp login system it always returns the invalid form submission

Tags: php

I am trying to create object oriented login system.

I've started to improve my **OOP skills**, by solving some rather easier issues, when building a website. So it started with a login system, I have followed a tutorial on youtube, that helped me made a Login class, but as it went on, it raised many doubts (The code is 100 lines so I'll pass on pasting it).

When I execute the code without entering value then the output is `invalid form submission`   **not return** `invalid username/password` etc.

When I enter the wrong username and password then return `invalid form submission`; 
It should not run properly...

Please help me

I enter my code here.

```
<?php

      class Login
      {
       private $_id;
       private $_username;
      private $_password;
      private $_passmd5; 

      private $_errors; 
      private $_access; 
      private $_login;
      private $_token;

      //create a function
      public function __construct()
      {

           $this->_errors = array();
           $this->_login  = isset($_POST['login'])?1:0;
           $this->_access = 0;
           $this->_token  = $_POST['token'];

           $this->_id      = 0;
           $this->_username= ($this->_login)? $this->filter($_POST['username']):$_SESSION['username'];
           $this->_password= ($this->_login)? $this->filter($_POST['password']): '';
           $this->_passmd5 = ($this->_login)? md5($this->_password) : $_SESSION['password'];

      }


      public function IsLoggedIn()
      {

            ($this->_login)? $this->VerifyPost() : $this->VerifySession();

          return $this->_access; 
      }

      public function filter($var)
      {
           return preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/','',$var);
      }

      public function VerifyPost()
      {
           try
           {
                if($this->IsTokenValid())

                    throw new Exception('Invalid Form Submission');

                if($this->IsDataValid())

                    throw new Exception('Invalid Form Data');

                if($this->VerifyDatabase())     

                    throw new Exception('Invalid Username / Password');


                $this->_access=1;
                $this->RegisterSession();

           }

           catch(Exception $e)
           {
                $this->_errors[]= $e->getMessage();
           }

      }

      public function VerifySession()
      {
          if($this->SessionExist() && $this->VerifyDatabase())
          {
                $this->_access=1;         
          }


      }

      public function VerifyDatabase()
      {
          include "db_connection.php";


          $q="select 'user_id' from user where username='".$this->_username."' and password='".$this->_passmd5."'";
          echo $q;
           $result=mysql_query($q);

          if(mysql_num_rows($result))
          {
              // list($this->_id)= @array_values(mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
              $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
              $this->_id= $row['user_id'];

               return true;
          }

          else
          {    
               return false;

          }
      }

      public function IsDataValid()
      {
          return preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,12}$/',$this->_username) && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,12}$/',$this->_password)?1:0;
      }

      public function IsTokenValid()
      {
         return (!isset($_SESSION['token']) || $this->_token != $_SESSION['token'])?0:1;
      }

      public function RegisterSession()
      {
          $_SESSION['user_id']=$this->_id;
          $_SESSION['username']=$this->_username;
          $_SESSION['password']=$this->_passmd5;
      }

      public function SessionExist()
      {
          return (isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['password']))? 1:0;
      }

      public function ShowErrors()
      {
          echo '<h3> Errors: </h3>';

          foreach($this->_errors as $key=>$value)
          {
              echo $value .'<br>';
          }
      }


}



?>
```

I handle this code in my login form i.e

```
enter code here
<?php

 session_start();

if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
  include "login.php";

  $login =new Login();

  if($login->IsloggedIn())
  {
      echo "success";
      //header("location:index.php");

  } 
  else
  {
      $login->ShowErrors();
  }

 }

 $token=$_SESSION['token']= md5(uniqid(mt_rand(),true));


?>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="login_form" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<p>
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input type="text" name="username" />
<br />

<label for="password">Pssword</label>
<input type="password" name="password" />
<br />
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?=$token;?>">
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />

</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: with only your class code it's actually hard to understand what's wrong. we should rather see how you handle form data. eg. do you correctly initialize the session? does !isset($_SESSION['token']) evaluate correctly? and where it's initially set the  $_SESSION['token'] variable?

Comment: I handle this code in my login form i.e <?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{      include "login.php";
      $login =new Login();
      if($login->IsloggedIn())
   echo "success";
      else
    $login->ShowErrors();
}
$token=$_SESSION['token']= md5(uniqid(mt_rand(),true));
?>
<form name="login_form" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
   Username:<input type="text" name="username">
   <br />
   Pssword:<input type="password" name="password">
   <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?=$token;?>">
   <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
</form>

Comment: please overrite your code with this one and tell me if it works: <?php session_start(); 
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {  include "login.php";  $login =new Login();  if($login->IsloggedIn()) echo "success";   else $login->ShowErrors();  } $token=$_SESSION['token']= md5(uniqid(mt_rand(),true)); ?>
<form name="login_form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">  Username:<input type="text" name="username"> <br /> Password:<input type="password" name="password"><input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token;?>"><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"> </form>

Comment: no, it should not work properly.. it always return invalid form submission.... please tell me try-catch block is supported by php5.3 and when try-catch block is used?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in token check

try to hide token validation exception by commenting the line:

```
throw new Exception('Invalid Form Submission');
```

and run the code

Comment: thank you.. but it will return success when enter wrong username and password..  & also return the password value is'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e'

Comment: did you try it?
it should return 'Invalid Username / Password'

Comment: I handle this code in my login form i.e <?php session_start(); if(isset($_POST['login'])) { include "login.php"; $login =new Login(); if($login->IsloggedIn()) echo "success"; else $login->ShowErrors(); } $token=$_SESSION['token']= md5(uniqid(mt_rand(),true)); ?> <form name="login_form" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"> Username:<input type="text" name="username"> <br /> Pssword:<input type="password" name="password"> <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?=$token;?>"> <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"> </form>

Comment: try to provide more information
1.the code
2. Input
3. Output

Comment: I have already added the code and input in my above comment..the output-- when i enter wrong username and password output is "invalid form submission" and not input data then also return "invalid form submission"